# t-sql numbering a continuous partition or run (sequences of same value in a field)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

This seems an exceedingly simple question but I can't figure out a one-pass (one-pass to my eyes) SQL query that will take the following and add a field `location number` which will be one 1 for the first run of `DAL`, 2 for the `BOS` run, and 3 for the next run of `DAL`. I know how to label the first partition (use two `ROW_NUMBER()`'s).

```
+---------+--------+-----------+----------+
| ITEM_ID | LOT_ID | ORGN_CODE | TRANS_ID |
+---------+--------+-----------+----------+
|      61 |  15161 | DAL       |   992342 |
|      61 |  15161 | DAL       |   992347 |
|      61 |  15161 | DAL       |  1043941 |
|      61 |  15161 | BOS       |  1061565 |
|      61 |  15161 | BOS       |  1064997 |
|      61 |  15161 | BOS       |  1064998 |
|      61 |  15161 | BOS       |  1064999 |
|      61 |  15161 | BOS       |  1065000 |
|      61 |  15161 | BOS       |  1065036 |
|      61 |  15161 | BOS       |  1065062 |
|      61 |  15161 | BOS       |  1065063 |
|      61 |  15161 | DAL       |  1065184 |
|      61 |  15161 | DAL       |  1065185 |
|      61 |  15161 | DAL       |  1065186 |
|      61 |  15161 | DAL       |  1065197 |
|      61 |  15161 | DAL       |  1065198 |
|      61 |  15161 | DAL       |  1083864 |
|      61 |  15161 | DAL       |  1083865 |
+---------+--------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: can you base your numbering on the Trans_ID?
`case when Trans_ID<1000000 location then number =1
case when Trans_ID between 1000000 and 1065184 then location number =1`...

Comment: @Boomer TRANS_ID has to be part of some `order by`, that seems certain; I could add `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by TRANS_ID)` and self-join and find the "switch" rows, but I haven't accepted the ugly truth yet

Comment: I'm thinking something along the lines of `sum( case when Orgn_Code <> ( select top 1 Orgn_Code from Foo where Trans_Id < outer.Trans_Id order by Trans_Id ) then 1 else 0 end ) )` as a starting point.

Answer (score 5):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT  *
    ,   DENSE_RANK() OVER(Order By GroupOrder) As GroupSequence
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order By TRANS_ID)
        -   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By ORGN_CODE Order By TRANS_ID)
            As GroupOrder
    FROM    yourTable
    )       As grp
```

One pass only and no cursors.  On SQL Server (tsql) this complies to a single scan of the source table.

Comment: Nice. Much better than my suggestion, but when it comes to number of "passes", I don't think it is much different the above. I believe analytic functions are done by a post-processing step on the result set.

Comment: Holy crap. My idea was to do `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TRANS) / ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ORGN_CODE ORDER BY TRANS)` but I couldn't see that I could get a meaningful number out of the two beyond labeling the first "run"

Comment: Maybe my intuition was right -- does this work when you have a lot of interleaving `ORGN_CODE` on the table ordered by `TRANS_ID` (say every other row)?

Comment: Yup.  I've always called this a "differential query", and you can do really cool things like this with them.

Comment: Here's an article by Itzak Ben-Gan that demonstrates: http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/calculating-concurrent-sessions-part-3

Answer (score 3):

I ran this on Postgresql. Perhaps you can apply on your rdbms. The idea is to use an analytic function to determine the orgn_code of the previous record. Then mark each row with a 0 or 1 if it has the same code as the previous or not respectively. Summing this column gives the incrementing number.

```
create table transaction( ITEM_ID int, LOT_ID int, ORGN_CODE text, TRANS_ID int);

insert into transaction values(61, 1561,  'DAL', 992342 );
insert into transaction values(61, 1561,  'DAL', 992347 );
insert into transaction values(61, 1561,  'DAL', 1043941 );
insert into transaction values(61, 1561,  'BOS', 1061565 );
insert into transaction values(61, 1561,  'BOS', 1064997 );
insert into transaction values(61, 1561,  'BOS', 1064998 );
insert into transaction values(61, 1561,  'BOS', 1064999 );
insert into transaction values(61, 1561,  'BOS', 1065000 );
insert into transaction values(61, 1561,  'BOS', 1065036 );
insert into transaction values(61, 1561,  'BOS', 1065062 );
insert into transaction values(61, 1561,  'DAL', 1065063 );
insert into transaction values(61, 1561,  'DAL', 1065184 );
insert into transaction values(61, 1561,  'DAL', 1065185 );
insert into transaction values(61, 1561,  'DAL', 1065186 );
insert into transaction values(61, 1561,  'DAL', 1065197 );
insert into transaction values(61, 1561,  'DAL', 1065198 );
insert into transaction values(61, 1561,  'DAL', 1083864 );
insert into transaction values(61, 1561,  'DAL', 1083865 );

SELECT item_id, lot_id, orgn_code, trans_id
      ,SUM( CASE WHEN orgn_code = previous_orgn_code THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) OVER(order by item_id, lot_id, trans_id) + 1 AS counter
  FROM ( SELECT item_id, lot_id, orgn_code, trans_id
               ,COALESCE( LAG(orgn_code) OVER(order by item_id, lot_id, trans_id)
                         ,orgn_code ) AS previous_orgn_code
           FROM transaction ) x
  ORDER BY item_id, lot_id, trans_id, orgn_code;
```

Result:

```
61  1561  "DAL"  992342   1
61  1561  "DAL"  992347   1
61  1561  "DAL"  1043941  1
61  1561  "BOS"  1061565  2
61  1561  "BOS"  1064997  2
61  1561  "BOS"  1064998  2
61  1561  "BOS"  1064999  2
61  1561  "BOS"  1065000  2
61  1561  "BOS"  1065036  2
61  1561  "BOS"  1065062  2
61  1561  "DAL"  1065063  3
61  1561  "DAL"  1065184  3
61  1561  "DAL"  1065185  3
61  1561  "DAL"  1065186  3
61  1561  "DAL"  1065197  3
61  1561  "DAL"  1065198  3
61  1561  "DAL"  1083864  3
61  1561  "DAL"  1083865  3
```

Comment: That's a triangular query, definitely not a one-pass solution.

Comment: I interpreted "one-pass" to actually mean a "single statement" solution. A "one-pass" sql solution will not exist with this table structure (if this is actually the result sought). A one-pass solution could be done with code walking through the cursor, but the performance will be bad compared to subquerying.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, In what way is this query a "triangular query"? It is using ´sum() over()` and `lag` so it will only work in SQL Server 2012 but the query plan shows a single table scan followed by a lot of other stuff including two sort operations but I don't see a "triangular query".

Comment: @RBarryYoung While your solution is cleaner (and better), I don't see it fundamentally different from this one. You use "dense_rank" on a subquery while I naively build my own dense_rank on a subquery.

Comment: @Glenn: My apologies, I think that I misread your query , as Mikael points out.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
create table transactions( ITEM_ID int, LOT_ID int, ORGN_CODE varchar(10), TRANS_ID int);

insert into transactions values(61, 1561,  'DAL', 992342 );
insert into transactions values(61, 1561,  'DAL', 992347 );
insert into transactions values(61, 1561,  'DAL', 1043941 );
insert into transactions values(61, 1561,  'BOS', 1061565 );
insert into transactions values(61, 1561,  'BOS', 1064997 );
insert into transactions values(61, 1561,  'BOS', 1064998 );
insert into transactions values(61, 1561,  'BOS', 1064999 );
insert into transactions values(61, 1561,  'BOS', 1065000 );
insert into transactions values(61, 1561,  'BOS', 1065036 );
insert into transactions values(61, 1561,  'BOS', 1065062 );
insert into transactions values(61, 1561,  'DAL', 1065063 );
insert into transactions values(61, 1561,  'DAL', 1065184 );
insert into transactions values(61, 1561,  'DAL', 1065185 );
insert into transactions values(61, 1561,  'DAL', 1065186 );
insert into transactions values(61, 1561,  'DAL', 1065197 );
insert into transactions values(61, 1561,  'DAL', 1065198 );
insert into transactions values(61, 1561,  'DAL', 1083864 );
insert into transactions values(61, 1561,  'DAL', 1083865 );

;WITH main as (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 0)) as sno,ITEM_ID,LOT_ID,ORGN_CODE,TRANS_ID from transactions)

,CTE as (
select sno,ITEM_ID,LOT_ID,ORGN_CODE,TRANS_ID,1 as seq from main where sno=1
union all
select t.sno,t.ITEM_ID,t.LOT_ID,t.ORGN_CODE ,t.TRANS_ID,CASE when c.ORGN_CODE=t.ORGN_CODE then seq else seq+1 end 
from main t inner join CTE c on  t.sno-1 =c.sno

)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```